# What does "immediately available" mean?

Tags: meaning

> It is best to have a duplicate immediately available.

Does it mean "It is best to use a duplicate immediately" or "It is best to have a duplicate which is readily available"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would go with the "It is best to have a duplicate which is readily available," particularly if there is a conditional such as "in the event of," "in case of," or "if." However, if in the context a duplicate is called for in every case, I would interpret that to mean that a duplicate should immediately be used.

Examples:

"In the event that carrying your passport is impossible, it is best to have a duplicate immediately available." - Have it readily available.

"An ID will be stored on file. It is best to have a duplicate immediately available." - Use the duplicate immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> "Immediately Available"

Immediately represents something Soon or instantly.

Available represents something that is there for use or accessible.

Put together it represents; Something that is Instantly Accessible to you or **Instantly Available to you**

> "It is best to have a duplicate which is readily available"

Also works well as a representation, its just saying to quickly have something there for use

Comment: 'Readily' is not the same as 'immediately'. 'Readily' means easily, while 'immediately' means instantly.